# Add custom validation in Update User Profile in Keycloak

Tags: jboss, single-sign-on, wildfly, keycloak, freemarker

I have added a custom attribute in `login-update-profile.ftl` named `organization`, it is able to save the input from user into Keycloak.

```html
<div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!}">
    <div class="${properties.kcLabelWrapperClass!}">
        <label for="user.attributes.organization" class="${properties.kcLabelClass!}">${msg("organization")}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="${properties.kcInputWrapperClass!}">
        <div class="${properties.kcInputWrapperClass!}">
            <input type="text" id="user.attributes.organization" name="user.attributes.organization" value="${(user.attributes.organization!'')}" class="${properties.kcInputClass!}" aria-invalid="<#if messagesPerField.existsError('organization')>true</#if>"
            />
        </div>

        <#if messagesPerField.existsError('organization')>
            <span id="input-error-organization" class="${properties.kcInputErrorMessageClass!}" aria-live="polite">
                ${kcSanitize(messagesPerField.get('organization'))?no_esc}
            </span>
        </#if>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to add validation for this field? I need to make it an obligatory field and meet certain condition (for example the length of the string). If the input is invalid, the error message is expected to be shown (like what we see in email or username field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the solution by creating a custom implementation of service provider `Review Profile` in `First Broker Login` flow. Here is the steps:

- Open keycloak's github repo and find the relevant Java codes for `Review Profile`. At the time of writing this answer (keycloak v15.0.2), we need 3 files: [AbstractIdpAuthenticator.java](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/authenticators/broker/AbstractIdpAuthenticator.java), [IdpReviewProfileAuthenticatorFactory.java](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/authenticators/broker/IdpReviewProfileAuthenticatorFactory.java), and [IdpReviewProfileAuthenticator.java](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/authenticators/broker/IdpReviewProfileAuthenticator.java)
- Make sure you are able to build a `.jar` using those files
- Open `IdpReviewProfileAuthenticator.java` and add this function:

```java
    public List<FormMessage> getCustomAttributeError(String organization) {
        List<FormMessage> errors = new ArrayList<>();

        // You can add more conditions & parameters to be validated
        if(Validation.isBlank(organization)){
            errors.add(new FormMessage("organization", "missingOrganizationMessage"));
        }

        return errors;
    }
```

- Go to `actionImpl` function and add this lines between `profile.update((attributeName, userModel)` and `catch (ValidationException pve)`:

```java
    if(getCustomAttributeError(profile.getAttributes().getFirstValue("organization")).size() > 0){
        throw new ValidationException();                
    }
```

- Add this lines in `catch (ValidationException pve)` after `List<FormMessage> errors`:

```java
    List<FormMessage> extraErrors = getCustomAttributeErrors(profile.getAttributes().getFirstValue("organization"));
    for(FormMessage error : extraErrors) {
        errors.add(error);
    }
```

- Open `IdpReviewProfileAuthenticatorFactory.java` go to `getDisplayType()` function and change the return value into `"Custom Review Profile"`
- Build the `.jar`, deploy it into keycloak, create a copy of `First Broker Login` flow we name `Custom First Broker Login`, and in `Custom First Broker Login` we replace `Review Profile` with `Custom Review Profile`
- Configure `Custom Review Profile` by clicking its action button, give it an alias, and turn `Update Profile on First Login` into `on`
- Bind the desired Identity Providers with the new `Custom First Broker Login`

Comment: Is it possible to adapt your code to the `Registration` workflow?

Comment: @FredericoSchardong it is not possible since it is derived from different SPI, but you can adapt the procedure. maybe start by customizing the [default registration form](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/forms/RegistrationProfile.java)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the experimental [user profile](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#user-profile).